# Inconsistent behaviour of Plymouth at shutdown

Tags: systemd, x11, shutdown, plymouth

I'm currently developing an application that should run in kiosk mode. On <del>shutdown</del> halt it shall show a screen with some instructions for the user for which plymouth is used.
The application is started by a systemd services that calls xinit (`/usr/bin/xinit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc /opt/kiosk/bin/app --`) and the shutdown screen is shown using plymouth's plymouth-halt.service. Unfornately this was not working out and I did't see the shutdown screen.

My idea was to fix both applications - the kiosk application and plymouth - to the same terminal (vt 1) so I added the parameter `vt1` to the application start (`/usr/bin/xinit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc /opt/kiosk/bin/app -- vt1`) and added the parameter `tty` to the plymouth service:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/plymouthd --mode=shutdown --attach-to-session --tty=tty1
ExecStartPost=-/bin/plymouth show-splash
```

Now I'm seeing inconsistent behaviour on different PCs despite all PCs are the same model and running the same operating system. Some installations show no shutdown screen at all (only a blank black screen), others are showing the screen sometimes, and some PCs showing it always as expected.

I'm running out of ideas, so my question is what can I do to make the shutdown behaviour consistent?